# No all Icons changing in unity launcher in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, launcher, icons

some icons change but not all of them in unity launcher, i already try via unity tweak tool but this icons just wont change. (using papirus icon)

apps not changing telegram, vivaldi, clementine etc this were not installed through snap.

any ideas how to fix this?

ubuntu 20.04 unity DE

Comment: the files for clementine and other apps show a lock on usr/share/icons